# notebook converted to strange format

Tags: notebooks

Somehow all code in a notebook turned into stuff like this. How can I reverse it back to normal code?

```
Cell[BoxData[{

 RowBox[{

  RowBox[{"saveTask", "=", 

   RowBox[{"CreateScheduledTask", "[", 

    RowBox[{

     RowBox[{"FrontEndExecute", "[", 

      RowBox[{"FrontEndToken", "[", "\"\<Save\>\"", "]"}], "]"}], ",", 

     RowBox[{"1", "*", "60"}]}], "]"}]}], ";"}], "\n", 

 RowBox[{

  RowBox[{"StartScheduledTask", "[", "saveTask", "]"}], ";"}]}], "Input",

 CellLabel->

  "In[192]:=",ExpressionUUID->"1b3f4631-a73c-464c-a691-9020c1a0
```

The orignal code is something like this:

```
saveTask = 
  CreateScheduledTask[FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["Save"]], 1*60];
StartScheduledTask[saveTask];
```

I tried this but still not work well.

```
Needs["AuthorTools`"] 
NotebookRestore[]
```

[image]

Comment: The notebook either got corrupted (in which case see if you have a backup of a previous version or search in the stack for that keyword for more help) or you opened it with a notepad/word editor and then saved it!? You really shouldn't do the latter ;-)

Comment: @HansOlo too bad that I don't have backup.

Comment: Sorry to hear that! Note for the future then: do frequent backups of your work and/or try using a cloud syncing service eg Dropbox, which keeps a history of all previous versions of the files (at least for a few days in the free version). I've found this approach to be stress-relieving especially for mission critical code (or near deadlines). Hopefully, some other members here will see this post and might have some idea.

Comment: @HansOlo I see. I use paid Google dirve but I'll check if they keep history as Dropbox as you said.

Comment: @HansOlo nice that you mentioned the history. I checked Google drive and it does keep the history.

Comment: Hopefully you can recover a working version of the notebook from there, good luck!

Comment: That stuff is the internal expressions of a notebook cell.  If you click on the right hand bracket of the cell (highlight the bracket) then choose Cell from the menu you should see the ShowExpression item checked.  Uncheck it and the cell will return to the formated version.

Comment: @josh probably you're right but it doesn't work in this case. 
`There was a syntax error on line 23 of the cell expression.
The error was:
Cell[BoxData[{

 RowBox[{

  RowBox[{"saveTask", "=", 

   RowBo`

Comment: @emnha:  Ok.  Then if you have no other alternative, how about going into the notebook and I believe you can edit it in text mode.  If that's the case, make a copy of it first, then edit in text mode at line 23 and delete that truncated string and then copy the full text version of the complete Cell command you get when you do the ShowExpression.  It's a stretch I know but if you get all the delimiters correct it should work.

Comment: @josh that probably works. I'm lucky that Google drive keeps all the history so I was able to recover the latest version before it corrupted.

Comment: This Resource Function might help: [SalvageNotebook](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SalvageNotebook/)